# How to check condition in "ref" attribute in Spring

Tags: spring

I'm new to Spring. Just wondering, is it possible to check condition within the "ref" attribute as follows?

```
<bean id="dbInfo" class="DatabaseProperties" factory-method="initDatabaseInformation"/>

<bean id="b1" class="someClass" >
    <property name="prop1" ref="#{ dbInfo.isValidUser? 'bean2' : 'bean3' }"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bean2" class="SomeClass1"/>

<bean id="bean3" class="SomeClass2"/>
```

I'm getting BeanCreationException by doing above. What would be the best practice to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would advise 1 of 4 methods (Options 2, 3 & 4 all amount to the same thing, it's just a question of where you put the code):**

1.*Spring Profiles, eg:*

```
<beans profile="valid">
  ...
  define 'b1' using 'bean2'
  ...
</beans>
<beans profile="invalid">
  ...
  define 'b1' using 'bean3'
  ...
</beans>
```

And then somewhere in your code you have to enable the correct Profile depending upon `dbInfo.isValidUser` - this is done when the Spring Context is bootstrapped.

2.*Use a factory method to create the required bean to inject:*

```
<bean id="b1" class="someClass" factory-method="createDependingUponValidUser">
    <property name="validbean" ref="bean2"/>
    <property name="invalidbean" ref="bean3"/>
    <property name="dbinfo" ref="dbinfo"/>
</bean>
```

With factory method:

```
public static SomeClass createDependingUponValidUser(DatabaseProperties dbinfo, SomeClass1 bean2, SomeClass2 bean3) {
        SomeClass b1 = new SomeClass();
        b1.setProp1(dbInfo.isValidUser() ? bean2 : bean3);
        return b1;
}
```

3.*Use a Java-based Spring Context Config*

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @AutoWired
    @Bean(name="b1")
    public SomeCLass b1(DatabaseProperties dbinfo, SomeClass1 bean2, SomeClass2 bean3) {
        SomeClass b1 = new SomeClass();
        b1.setProp1(dbInfo.isValidUser() ? bean2 : bean3);
        return b1;
    }
}
```

(Java-style config and XML-style config can be mixed :-)

4.*Do the switch in the `SomeClass` constructor (or `setProp1()` method) of `'b1'`*

```
public SomeClass(DatabaseProperties dbinfo, SomeClass1 bean2, SomeClass2 bean3) {
    this.prop1 = dbInfo.isValidUser() ? bean2 : bean3;
}
```